# How to send e-mail to choices made by user input through workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

[image]I have a list where in users can submit certain information and same is picked up by a group to resolve it.

So in the user input form we have an option of "Request team" which has a list of group Email IDs. So the user can choose multiple teams to through a list of choices and an Email is sent to those selections.

I am not able to figure out how to build a workflow which identified the selections made by the user under requesting teams and send E-mails accordingly.

See the screenshot for more clarity.

Any advice and suggestion on this is greatly appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use a workflow it can be done using SharePoint designer workflows.

I am guessing you do not have SharePoint designer.
It is a free tool provided by microsoft, so please download it for the version of SharePoint you have (SharePoint designer for 2013/2010/2007)

1. If you do have it, or once you download it, run your SharePoint designer.
2. Once you start it you will need to open your SharePoint site, which contains the list you need that workflow for. So click Open Site and enter the URL.
3. Either navigate to the list and click "List Workflow" in the ribbon, or click "List Workflow" from Home and select the list you need.
4. Enter name and description for workflow and you will be taken to workflow content editor.
5. Click "Condition" in the ribbon. 
   You will define what conditions need to be met for the workflow to send emails. If you want your WF to always send once a new item is created, simply select "If current item field equals value", select "Requesting team" as the field, click operator (by default it is set to "equals") and select "is not empty"
6. Now click "Action" in the ribbon.
7. Select "Send email".
8. Click "These users" to modify the users.
9. Click the book icon next to "To:" field.
10. Select "Workflow Lookup for a User".
11. Leave "Current Item" as data source.
12. Set "Requesting team" as Field from source.
13. Set "Email Address" to Return the field data email address.
14. Define email content, you can use data from your SharePoint to customize the messages.
15. Set the workflow triggers. 
    To do that, click "Workflow settings" in the ribbon and select "Start workflow automatically when an item is created" under Start Options.
16. Save and publish the workflow. You can do that by clicking corresponding buttons in the ribon.

Your workflow should be ready. Make sure that group members have correctly defined emails and you web application SMTP settings are correct for outgoing emails.

That is out of the box way.
You can also use third party solutions for an easier management. For example i believe you could use an alerting tool to send these emails. There are a lot of those, i would recommend JungleBell as it is probably the easiest to use:
http://www.enovapoint.com/junglebell/download-free-trial/

Comment: Hi Donald, Thank you so much for the detailed explanation, I really appreciate it. I have sharepoint designer already installed. The Requesting team is a selection box or a check box with multiple selection options enabled. So there is a existing list of E-mail Ids which the user should select. For example once they checksay 2 Email Ids box an Email has to go to those Email IDs as well.

Comment: No problem. Please try it out and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi Donald, Thank you so much for the detailed explanation, I really appreciate it. I have sharepoint designer already installed. The Requesting team is a selection box or a check box with multiple selection options enabled. So there is a existing list of E-mail Ids which the user should select. For example once they check say 2 Email Ids box an Email has to go to those two Email IDs. I followed all the steps mentioned by you but in the look up window while selecting the "return field as" I am not getting "Email address" option instead I am getting choices, delimited (see the image).

Comment: I presume that because the column is a choice type hence we are not getting the return field as E-mail address if it was a person or group type we would have got that option. what do you say Donald?

Comment: That is correct. If the column was Person or Group type, than you would have an option of Email. Because "Person" contains all that information and you simply choose which column to use. In your case, emails are already stored in that column so you can use them directly. Workflow should be able to use those emails if you return them as string.

Comment: That is what I am unable to figure out how to use them directly. can you please help.

Comment: How to return the workflow the strings?

Comment: My bad. You should choose to return column data as choices. As shown in the screenshot you provided. When defining workflow recipients, choose "Return field as" as "Choices, comma delimited". It works for me.

Comment: Ok let me try !

Comment: Yup its working with Choice, comma delimited. thanks Donald! :)